Identify why Cloud Firestore / Firebase Security Rules aren't working
I'm currently in the process of building my first proper app in Flutter and have spent some time setting up an offline-first architecture where data-objects are saved locally in SQLite first and then will sync with Firestore, and settings values are saved locally into shared preferences and will also sync with firestore.
I have everything up and running as needed until when it comes to switching out the userId that represents each user - originally this was generated by Firebase auth, but I would like to have the userId generated by the app using the UUID library instead to avoid situations where someone might want to use the app offline.
To achieve this it seems that I need to create a new collection in firestore that maps the Firebase auth userID to the UUID userID:

You can then see a newly created collection of data under the userID created by the uuid library (65509cc4-9114-4759-b178-[redacted]) in the 'users' collection:

This should allow me to permission access to the 'users' collection based on the values found in the 'userMappings' collection - here's the Security Rules I have currently:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Rules for userMappings collection
    match /userMappings/{firebaseUid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == firebaseUid;
    }

    // Rules for users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserId() == userId;
      
      match /profiles/{profileId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserId() == userId;
        
        match /tasks/{taskId} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserId() == userId;
        }
        
        match /livetasks/{liveTaskId} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserId() == userId;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Function to get the userId (UUID) from the userMappings collection
  function getUserId() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userMappings/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userId;
  }
}

However when I run this code the app throws firebase authentication/access errors.
Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here? Or how I can test what value is being returned by: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userMappings/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userId; ?
I've managed to identify that it is the getUserID() function causing the issue but cannot seem to resolve the issue. If I change the function to the below it still fails:
  function getUserId() {
    let userMappingDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userMappings/$(request.auth.uid));
    return userMappingDoc.exists() ? userMappingDoc.data.userId : "65509cc4-9114-4759-b178-[redacted]"; 
  }

However, the below change allows the app to run without issue:
  function getUserId() {
    return "65509cc4-9114-4759-b178-[redacted]";
  }

This leads me to believe that the userMappingDoc parameter created in the middle version of the function is picking up a value, but it's not "65509cc4-9114-4759-b178-[redacted]" - or at least not this value alone.

You'll have an easier time debugging your security rules if you use the rules emulator.

The get() function in security rules does not function like it does in the Firestore SDK. If the target document doesn't exist (or doesn't exist yet), userMappingDoc will simply be null. Which means it throws an exception when using accessing .data or .exists() (from a null object) and immediately fail the entire rule. You either want to null-check the returned value first or try using getAfter() if this is a batched update. The rules emulator that Doug mentioned can help identify what is going on.

A word of caution, your current rules around /userMappings/{firebaseUid} allow users to update their linked UUID with no further validation. This would allow a user to link to another user's UUID and its data. You'll need a UUID-to-FirebaseID map to show who owns a particular UUID with appropriate mutation prevention, or store the associated Firebase ID in the  /users/{userId} once known.

Thanks for the suggestions! Installing the rules emulator seems like a lot of additional work (installing Java, Node and npm, along with other setup steps) to update one small feature when the rules were working for me just fine before I tried to attempt to map the uuid userID to the firebase userID - I think I'm going to attempt to code around this instead.

"Coding around this" could end up costing you more time and headache going forward as opposed to starting with the right tools in place and understanding the true source of the problem.

Thanks @DougStevenson - absolutely agreed, however in this case I actually think I was probably going about it in the wrong way and complicating the issue more than needed.

@DougStevenson I don't actually need a userID for the app to work, it's only required so we can store the user data in the appropriate place in firestore so it makes sense (i believe) to only create a userID when the app syncs tasks with firestore for the first time and to save the firebase created userID in shared preferences rather than the other way around (generating a userID in uuid and then saving into firestore).
I'm very new to all of this so please excuse any noob reasoning.

thanks @samthecodingman - very helpful

@Steve, its not required to install the local emulators to test your rules as the Rules tab of the Firebase Console has its own simulator (I wrongly assumed this was mentioned in the linked docs, but its on an earlier page). The difference between the two is that the simulator tests against actual data in your database and can be a little cumbersome to use, whereas the emulator approach allows you to unit test your rules and ensure that problems don't reach your production rules.
